# O que significa a expressão "de plantão" como em "os críticos de plantão certamente dirão que..."?

Tags: significado, expressões, significado-em-contexto

A mim, parece ser uma expressão ***relativamente nova*** e, por *relativamente nova*, eu quero dizer ***não mais que 30 anos*** na língua portuguesa.

Eu entendo o significado como algo mais ou menos genérico do tipo "aqueles que estão lendo ou ouvindo minha fala ou escrita".  Podemos ser mais específicos do que isso? Podemos interpretar como:

- aqueles que estão sempre atentos a esse tema?
- os que estão na ativa?
- que estão trabalhando no momento e que respondem de acordo com suas profissões?
- que estão sempre prontos a rebater qualquer afirmação diferente de suas crenças arraigadas?
- que estão sempre aguardando uma oportunidade para se manifestar?

**ADDENDUM**: Não me refiro a profissionais que trabalham em regime de plantões, como médicos, bombeiros, soldados, policiais, etc, que são subordinados a uma chefia e/ou que recebem honorários.   O "de plantão" a que me refiro não tem o sentido literal da expressão. Por exemplo, "aos otários de plantão, eu respondo que...", "aos manés de plantão, eu dou o seguinte conselho..." ou, "aos desocupados de plantão, eu não estou a caça de sugestões".  Por esse motivo é que acho ser um uso relativamente recente e talvez restrito a pt-BR.

Qual o registro mais antigo da expressão?  Ela tem um significado genérico ou pode ser mais específica em relação ao contexto em que é usada? O seu uso é restrito a pt-BR?

Comment: A resposta que tinha dado o Jacinto já quase responde à última pergunta ;)

Comment: @Jacinto   "...creio que o sentido figurado já é o de pessoa sempre pronta a botar abaixo, falar sem saber do que fala, como se estivesse literalmente de plantão para o efeito."  Sim, é um dos sentidos.  Outro sentido semelhante seria como no caso de "aos idiotas de plantão, eu digo que..."

Comment: No caso geral vejo ser usado no sentido "que estão a postos nesse momento". Especificamente sobre o "críticos de plantão", talvez mais no sentido de "que estão sempre/agora prontos a rebater (qualquer) afirmação diferente de suas crenças arraigadas".

Comment: **Eu não entendo esse tipo de pergunta**. Você disse: Não me refiro a profissionais que trabalham em regime de plantões, Mas é isso mesmo que quer dizer "um crítico de plantão". Usar uma expressão como essa só pode se ligar ao sarcasmo, ué. É uma forma de desprestigiar o fulano. Que nem num hospital, tem sempre uma cara de plantão.  A ideia aqui de uma pessoas que fica de plantão é que está "sempre lá".

Comment: @Lambie   Acredito que você nunca tenha ouvido a expressão:  "aos idiotas de plantão, eu quero dizer que...",  "os desocupados de plantão certamente irão dizer que...".  Conforme você pode ver, idiotas e desocupados não dão plantões, não trabalham em regime de plantão e nem ficam de plantão em seu sentido literal.  A expressão é relativamente nova e você, morando fora do Brasil, talvez nunca tenha ouvido.

Comment: Meu caro Centaurus, não é **uma expressão**. É um comentário sarcástico. Nem tudo está já escrito ou já existente. Se fosse assim, faria as minhas malas (expressão francesa). Existe na linguagem todo tipo de creatividade. Eis um exemplo, e muito bem dito na minha humilde opinião. Os critícos de plantão são os que estão sempre aí para "prestar serviços". Será que você não pega o aspeto cómico da coisa?? :) É muito engraçado. Até poderia traduzir isso ao francês ou ao inglês com o mesmo sentido....os desocupados de plantão são como funcionários que vão ao trabalho e não fazem nada,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vamos primeiro definir o que é o "plantão":
*"serviço noturno ou em horas normalmente sem expediente em hospital, farmácia, fábrica, redação de jornal etc"* 
[Dicionário Caldas Aulete: Definição de *'plantão'*](http://www.aulete.com.br/plant%C3%A3o)

Aqui no Brasil é um serviço onde a pessoa está "o dia todo" trabalhando naquilo.
Como médicos, farmacêuticos...

Então essa expressão ao pé da letra, fala sobre as pessoas que estão "o dia todo" atentas ao que você fala, faz... mas no sentido pejorativo (sentido ruim).

Ex.:

*"Aos críticos de plantão, entendam a situação"*: Para aqueles que vivem a me criticar, pensem antes de falar.

*"Os críticos de plantão certamente dirão que eu estou errado"*: Para aquelas pessoas que vivem criticando elas vão falar que eu estou errado.

Das suas ponderações, ao meu ver, as que melhor definiram a expressão foram:

> - aqueles que estão sempre atentos a esse tema
> - que estão sempre prontos a rebater qualquer afirmação diferente de suas crenças arraigadas
> - que estão sempre aguardando uma oportunidade para se manifestar

Sobre as suas outras perguntas:

> Qual o registro mais antigo da expressão?

Eu realmente não sei, mas eu sempre ouvi ela no Brasil.

> Ela tem um significado genérico ou pode ser mais específica em relação ao contexto em que é usada?

Como você viu nos exemplos, ela é bem genérica. Basicamente fala sobre alguém que está sempre atento ao tema da frase, normalmente no sentido pejorativo.

> O seu uso é restrito a pt-BR?

Também não tenho conhecimento, mas não ouço os portugueses usarem tanto ela.

Comment: Bem vindo ao site.  Já começaste com uma boa resposta.

Comment: Apenas retirei o frase final, evitando agradecimento e coisas do tipo. Mas, parabéns pela resposta!

Answer (score 1):

Ótima dúvida! Crítico de plantão é aquele que sempre é crítico, sem discernir a situação em que, ao invés de uma reprovação, cabe um elogio.

Comment: Olá, o autor da pergunta tem outras dúvidas além do que está exposto no título. Se possível, tente sanar todas as dúvidas do autor.

Answer (score 0):

Em Portugal usa-se muito esta expressão, geralmente com o sentido de tarefa forçada num horário pré-definido diferente do horário de trabalho geral. Exemplo: amanhã durante a madrugada vou estar de plantão à espera que aconteça alguma coisa.
Mas também, ocasionalmente, em sentido figurado como no que foi perguntado. No meu entendimento, os "críticos de plantão" são gentinha que não faz mais nada senão avaliar, geralmente em sentido negativo (justa ou injustamente, isso é secundário), o que os outros fazem; ou seja, que estão "de plantão" para as ideias e os actos dos outros, pois deles não vêm nem ideias, nem actos para além da crítica.